# How can I connect to a Checkpoint VPN using specific credentials, using Windows 8.1?

Tags: windows-8.1, vpn

When I upgraded to Windows 8.1, the computability advisor told my that my Checkpoint Secure client would be incompatible, and promptly removed it.

I understand that it is possible to connect to Checkpoint via the VPN client built in with Windows 8.1. I've created a VPN connection, and told it to authenticate with user/password, but Windows doesn't actually give me a prompt to supply my username nor password - how can I tell it what to use?

Answer (score 0):

You can setup the username and password during the VPN creation.

while at the start screen start typing VPN - it will show an icon for managing VPN connections - click on that and you will see dialog below and allows you to enter the username and password

[image]

I noticed that for CheckPoint the username is grayed out there but if I try to connect, I am am prompted for the credentials at the connection time:

[image]

Comment: For me, I'm not prompted for the user name/credentials; instead it goes straight to "Verifying your credentials" and then fails with "Failed to communicate with server"

Comment: Hmm, it almost sounds like it is trying to use the user you are logged on with. It might be a server side settings but I can't help with that as I don't have control over the VPN box.